# Can't set session lifetime with PDOSessionHandler Silex

Tags: php, symfony, session, session-cookies, silex

I'm building a small backoffice project with Silex and I'm using the `PdoSessionHandler` to store sessions in the database. I've already succeded at storing the session in database but it seems that setting `cookie_lifetime` parameter to the $app variable changes the expiration of the cookie but not the session lifetime in database.

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SessionServiceProvider(), [
    'session.storage.options' => [
        'name' => '_PROJECTBACKOFFICE',
        'cookie_lifetime' => 15552000,
    ],
]);
```

After taking a look at the code of `PdoSessionHandler` looks like the value of the session lifetime in database takes the value from the php.ini setting `session.gc_maxlifetime`:

```
$maxlifetime = (int) ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime');
```

And stores the value into the database field

```
$mergeStmt = $this->pdo->prepare($mergeSql);
$mergeStmt->bindParam(':id', $sessionId, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
$mergeStmt->bindParam(':data', $data, \PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$mergeStmt->bindParam(':lifetime', $maxlifetime, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

So, looks like the only way to increase the session lifetime is by changing the php.ini setting. Has anyone succeded in changing the lifetime in database programatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in `.htaccess`, it's the only way. It must be higher than the lifetime set in `SessionServiceProvider()` settings :

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime "3600"
```

Comment: I've done that with php's function `ini_set`, but I was looking for something that doesn't mean to change php.ini configuration.

Comment: You don't need to change your `php.ini`, just create a `.htaccess` file.

Comment: I know that, but if I want to have different session values for different users... I'd like a programmatical solution.

Comment: No, you just need to set your apache session expiration time higher than the one in `SessionServiceProvider()`. Then you can do whatever you want in `SessionServiceProvider()` configuration.

Comment: That's not true, `SessionServiceProvider` get the value to `sess_lifetime` from `ini_get` function not from the parameters' configuration.

Comment: It can guess, but you can pass parameters as shown here : http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/session.html

Comment: I read the documentation too, but I have implemented and it does not work in database with the `PdoSessionHandler`, it does not sets this value in the session lifetime field. That's the problem.